# CASE WHEN there is no previous value

Tags: mysql

I have this table where I only want to look at AB

```
ID     CODE       COUNT   
102    AB         7
101    AB         6
100    AC         23    //not important!!!!
99     AB         26
98     AB         1
97     AB         0
96     AB         50
```

Where I want to count the difference between each step, but with some cases inbetween

**Case 1**:
If the value is suddenly 50 without a previous value, take 0 as the previous value.

**Case 2**:
If the *difference* is suddenly negative, also take 0 as the previous value.

So my result should be:

```
ID      COUNT   DIFFERENCE  
96      50      50      //CASE 1, take 0 as previous value
97       0       1
98       1      25
99      26       6      //CASE 2, take 0 instead of 26 as previous value
101      6       1
```

The code that I have now is:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98051/3

How should I adjust it to make it work like I want it to?

Kind regards

*ps: if this is unclear to you, please ask and I will try to improve my question*

Comment: Isn't the drop from 26 to 1 sudden?

Comment: Yes, but it happens sometimes in my application

Comment: Could you please show us the desired output (right now it does not become clear, what you're aiming for). BTW. "difference is [..] negative but bigger than 0" does not make any sense. Please elaborate.

Comment: Thankyou, horrible mistake in the explanation, hope that it makes sense now =p

Answer (score 0):

I do not completely understand what are you trying to accomplish exactly, but I am guessing that you want something like this:

```
SET @previous_count:=0;

SELECT id, code, `count`, 
IF(`count` - @previous_count, `count`) as difference,
@previous_count:=`count` 
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what 'suddenly' means in this context, but maybe something like this can work for you...

```
SELECT a.id
     , a.code
     , a.count
     , b.count bcount
     , CASE WHEN a.count = 50 AND b.count IS NULL THEN 50
            WHEN a.count - b.count <= 0 THEN 0
            ELSE a.count - b.count
            END difference
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.* 
            , COUNT(*) rank
         FROM some_table x
         JOIN some_table y
           ON y.code = x.code
          AND y.id <= x.id
        GROUP
           BY x.id
     ) a
  LEFT
  JOIN   
     ( SELECT x.* 
            , COUNT(*) rank
         FROM some_table x
         JOIN some_table y
           ON y.code = x.code
          AND y.id <= x.id
        GROUP
           BY x.id
     ) b
    ON b.code = a.code
   AND b.rank = a.rank -1;
```